# XSD - how can I ensure the existance of a particular element with a given attribute?

Tags: xsd, schematron

I'm trying to add extra validation to [jdpl](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/jpdl.html) process-definition files using XSD.

We have a couple of rules we want to add; but the one that's causing me problems is that there must exist one "node" element with it's "name" attribute = "Problem".

so this is valid:

```
<process-definition name='sample'>
    <node name="Problem">
    </node>
    <node name="Do Work">
    </node>
</process-definition>
```

and this isn't

```
<process-definition name='sample'>
    <node name="Do Work">
    </node>
</process-definition>
```

So, to summarise, the rules I need to enforce are

- node attribute having the value "Problem"
- existence of 1 node with name="Problem"
- allowing any number of nodes with other names

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Must you call "Problem" node simply node?
If you can change the name it can be done

Comment: Yeah Robert it must be still a node because this is extra validation on top of what jpdl does.

This validation is particular to our application and changing the format of the document would cause the underlying jbpm framework to fall over.

Thanks

Comment: Ok then I have a crazy suggestion... change the node to something else and then post-process to replace that something else back to node. Done a similar trick before. Not elegant but works

Comment: Ha ha. I'd been thinking along similar lines - I wanted to use an xslt transformation to execute the rules and output an xml document of "validation errors".

Thanks for taking the time Robert.

Comment: You can also use XSLT or something else to throw out the "noise" i.e. the nodes without the "Problem"-attribute and validate the result with XSD. Validating completely with XSLT is doable but it's not the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that's not possible with XSD.

Due to performance reasons XML-Schema is designed to never look ahead and never look back beyond the current node. That means that it must always be defined where the validator is in the schema-tree. And that makes requirements like this impossible to define with XSD.

Comment: Thanks TToni. I ended up writing my validation rules in Schematron.